# oracle expdp is giving me insufficient privileges if invoked in a certain way

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file

I have a batch script that exports database dump using expdp , it works perfectly fine when I run this batch script alone. Now I have a requirement that I have to run a different batch script that basically sets some environment variables , this batch script has to be run before batch containing the expdp. The problem I am facing is after executing the other batch script, when I run batch containing expdp it throws me

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

I also checked user using "whoami" it shows right user and I also checked that the user is in "ora_dba" group. Basically all it boils down to is : Is there any way to easily check if user's privileges are somehow not visible in that DOS session ?

Comment: So you are not sure what this other batch file does, but expect someone to figure out the problem?  What does the command-line for your expdp look like?  Are you passing in credentials on that command?

Comment: I looked at the other script, I can tell you that all it does is just set some environment variables. It also has some pushd, popd  in between, but I don't think that will cause any issue. My expdp command line is : %oracle_home%\bin\expdp %username%/%password%  schemas=%user_schema% dumpfile=oracle_dumpfile.dmp logfile=oracle_export.log directory=dump_dir

Comment: So how do you know username is the same?

Comment: I am providing same user name as I was using before when running the export batch script alone

Comment: Please post as much of the files as you can.

Comment: Guys, I found the problem. The other batch file was setting TNS_ADMIN to some path. When I unset it, it works fine! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post an answer and accept it. Don't change your title AND question...

Comment: Ok. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other batch file was setting TNS_ADMIN to some path. When I unset it, it works fine!